# Who owns the gpg key 4AEE18F83AFDEB23 and how did it sign a commit in my GitHub repo?

Tags: gnupg, code-signing, openpgp, github

This commit in my GiHub repo is signed by a key I don't recognize: https://github.com/jonathancross/jc-docs/pull/2/commits/124672699991af75dd2454831670758f08bc74ab

What is going on here?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

GitHub *itself* is signing commits made through the online editor using the key [`0x4AEE18F83AFDEB23`](https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x4AEE18F83AFDEB23&fingerprint=on&op=index):

[image: GitHub Screenshot: This commit was created on GitHub.com and signed with a verified signature using GitHub’s key.]

From: https://help.github.com/articles/about-gpg/

*GitHub will automatically sign commits you make using the GitHub web interface. These commits will have a verified status on GitHub. You can verify the signature locally using the public key available at https://github.com/web-flow.gpg*

Answer (score 14):

To add to [@Jonathan Cross](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/16036/jonathan-cross)'s [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/173494/159064)...

## Signature rules

### When will GitHub sign commits

- GitHub will sign commits made using the web UI
- GitHub will sign standard merges made using the web UI
- GitHub will sign commits made by squashing to merge using the web UI

### When will GitHub not sign commits

- GitHub will not sign commits made by rebasing with the web UI

## Why is a different key used than mine

This is because the web UI has no access to the private key, so it has to use its own key.

Comment: Hi! Would you know why would GitHub not sign commits made by rebasing with the web UI?

Comment: I do not know, my guess would be that it does not re-sign the commits after rebasing them as an oversight, rather than anything deliberate

Comment: Very likely, because rebasing is affecting commits of a different author, and this could else be used to fake commits of other uses to appear as signed